# Chrome extension : Is it possible to keep extension open on reload?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, reload

I'm building an google extension that inserts html in page and shows a menu on browser action icon click and I don't find way to keep my extension open when I reload the page. So on every reload, we have to active it again from Browser Action icon.

Below the **manifest** file

```
{

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/icone.png",
        "default_title": "show menu"
    },

    "icons" : {
        "128" : "img/icone_128.png",
        "48" : "img/icone_48.png",
        "32" : "img/icone_32.png",
        "24" : "img/icone_24.png",
        "16" : "img/icone_16.png"
    },

    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "p|layer",
    "version": "1.0.4",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "<all_urls>"],
            "css":["css/grid.css", "css/font-awesome.min.css"],
            "js":["js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js","js/jquery-ui.js", "js/jquery.nicefileinput.min.js"]
        }
    ],

    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff"
    ],

    "permissions": [ "activeTab"]

 }
```

script (**background.js**) injecting contentscript

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) { //Fired when User Clicks ICON

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,
    {"file": "js/contentscript.js"},

    function () { // Execute your code
        console.log("Script Executed .. "); // Notification on Completion
    });

    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {file: "css/grid.css"});
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {file: "css/font-awesome.min.css"});
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(tab.id, {file: "css/slider.css"});

});
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Oups, I translated my message and "Hi everyone," did not come with and editing doesn't work :s

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do or what the problem is. You can inject your menu via `content_scripts` in manifest, then it will be re-injected on reload. Show some code!

Comment: I edited my post with some code, well I try to explain again simply. when we click on the icon, my menu with options appear but when I reload my page the extension close and all disappear. I need that all stays displayed in current tab.

Comment: That's better. Now what are you trying to achieve? Your button click activates the menu for the current tab apparently, and what should happen then? Should it ever be deactivated?

Comment: Decidedly, my finger fails a lot today ... when we click on the icon, my menu with options appear but when I reload the extension close and all disappear. I need that all stays displayed (all is saved in localStorage), it will be annoying if user has to open extension on every reload.

Comment: If you reload _the extension_? Users should only experience this on auto-updates. But yes, you're thinking in the right direction (maintain a cache of "activated" `tabId`s). I still don't get two points. 1) Any DOM with your menu you've injected in a page should survive extension reload, 2) As it is, _page_ reload or navigation will make your menu disappear - is that intended?

Comment: My extension allows users to upload a mockup in local or online page they are coding, so my extension has to stay displayed (my menu with input file, some divs for options ...etc). That's not really a reload of extension but it's current tab reload. Do you get what problem?

Answer (score 0):

So, from the comments the problem was inferred: your button click activates your content script, but a page reload clears it. Assuming you want the button click to act as a toggle:

**1) Always inject the content script / CSS, but don't show the UI immediately:**

```js
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": [ "<all_urls>"],
    "css": ["css/grid.css", "css/font-awesome.min.css", "css/slider.css"],
    "js": [
      "js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js", "js/jquery-ui.js",
      "js/jquery.nicefileinput.min.js", "js/contentscript.js"
    ]
  }
],
```

**2) Keep track of "activated" tabs:**

```js
var activeTabs = {};

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( function(tab){
  var active;
  if(activeTabs[tab.id]){
    delete activeTabs[tab.id];
    active = false;
  } else {
    activeTabs[tab.id] = true;
    active = true;
  }

  /* (part 3) */
});

chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener( function(tabId){
  delete activeTabs[tabId];
});

chrome.tabs.onReplaced.addListener( function(newTabId, oldTabId){
  if(activeTabs[oldTabId]) activeTabs[newTabId] = true;
  delete activeTabs[oldTabId];
});
```

**3) Use messaging to show/hide UI:**

Content script:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(message. sender, sendResponse){
  if(message.showUI) showUI();
  if(message.hideUI) hideUI();
});
```

Background script:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener( function (tab) {
  var active;
  /* (part 2) */

  if(active) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {showUI: true});
  } else {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {hideUI: true});
  }
});
```

Additional robustness can be added for the cases of *extension* reload, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Thank Xan, I didn't understand all your post, if 2) is background.js or not. But I'll watch that more deeply this week-end.